# How to use a riverpod family provider without passing parameter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management, riverpod

Is there a way to access an instance of a provided "`.family`" change notifier (which has already been instantiated, passing the right parameters) without passing the parameters again?

**IN PROVIDER**

When you create a provider of a ChangeNotifier (which requires parameters), you can get the same change notifier it's providing with `Provider.of<ChangeNotif>(context)`;

```
class ChangeNotif extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  const ChangeNotif(this.id);
}

ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChangeNotif("dash"));
```

Once the provider has been created with its right params, you can get whatever it's providing anywhere down that widget tree without any syntax like `Provider.of<ChangeNotif("dash")>(context)` but rather `Provider.of<ChangeNotif>(context)`.

**IN RIVERPOD**

Since you have to pass the parameters to the provider when getting an instance of it, I've had to assign the provider to a variable in order to pass it down to its children which need the change notifier the provider is providing.

```
final changeNotifProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.family<ChangeNotif, String>((ref, id) => ChangeNotif(id));

class A extends HookWidget {
  build() {
    final _changeNotifProvider = changeNotifProvider("dash");
    final _changeNotif = useProvider(_changeNotifProvider);

    return Column(
     children: [
       B(),
       c(_changeNotifProvider),
     ]
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the instantiated `_changeNotif` without passing it as a parameter to a child widget? Is there any way to get the same instance of _changeNotif in another widget that isn't a child of A (like using `Provider.of<ChangeNotif>(context)` in Provider without having to pass new parameters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the riverpod examples of how it solves that problem [Marvel Example](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/master/examples/marvel/lib/src/screens/home.dart)

The advantage of using riverpo family vs Provider package is that provider doesn't let you read multiple instances of the same class down the widget tree and riverpod family doesn't have that restriction

in Provider

```
MultiProvider(
   providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotif>(
        create: (_) => ChangeNotif('dash')
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotif>(
        create: (_) => ChangeNotif('dash2')
      ),
    // and many more of the same provider but different initial value
   ].
   child: MyWidget()
);
```

Then in `MyWidget` when doing `Provider.of<ChangeNotif>(context)` you only get the last one created by MultiProvider, cannot differentiate multiples providers of the same type, now in riverpod a solution to that and a way to pass down the family would be to use a ScopedProvider with the initial value.

```
final _idProvider = ScopedProvider<String>(null);

class A extends HookWidget {

  @override
  Widget build() {
    final _changeNotif = useProvider(changeNotifProvider("dash"));

    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
         _idProvider .overrideWithValue("dash"),
      ],
      child: Column(
        children: [
          B(),
          c(),
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Now all widgets down (B and C) can read the parameter used to create the family, if the provider already exists it will retrieve it without creating it anew

```
class A extends HookWidget {

  @override
  Widget build() {
    final id = useProvider(_idProvider);
    final _changeNotif = useProvider(changeNotifProvider(id)); //the ProviderContainer will check if there is already a family with that id and retrieve it

    return Text(_changeNotif.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension to get all the instances for `StateNotifierProviderFamily` instances, but you could also do this for `ChangeNotifierProviderFamily`. You do need to register them in the provider:

````dart
extension StateNotifierProviderFamilyExtension<
    Notifier extends StateNotifier<Value>,
    Value,
    Param> on StateNotifierProviderFamily<Notifier, Value, Param> {
  /// Get all the registered versions of this `StateNotifierProviderFamily`
  ///
  /// This function requires a reader to the current `ProviderScope` to
  /// get the `familyKeysStorageProvider`
  ///
  /// The family needs to be registered with the `familyKeysStorageProvider`,
  /// like this:
  ///
  /// ```dart
  /// final keyStorage = ref.read(familyKeysStorageProvider(myProvider));
  /// keyStorage.state.add(myKey);
  /// ```
  Iterable<T> all<T extends StateNotifierProvider<Notifier, Value>>(
      Reader read) {
    return read(_familyKeysStorageProvider(this))
        .state
        .map((key) => call(key) as T);
  }

  Set<dynamic> keys(Reader read) =>
      read(_familyKeysStorageProvider(this)).state;
  void addKey(Reader read, dynamic key) => this.keys(read).add(key);
}

/// Use this provider to register keys for a `StateNotifierProviderFamily`
/// object.
///
/// After registration of the keys, it is possible to retrieve all registered
/// instances with the `all(Reader read)` method on `StateNotifierProviderFamily`
final _familyKeysStorageProvider =
    StateProvider.family<Set<dynamic>, StateNotifierProviderFamily>((ref, key) {
  return {};
});
````

You can register like this:

```dart
final myStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family<
    MyStateNotifier,
    MyState,
    MyKey>(
  (ref, key) {
    myStateProvider.addKey(ref.read, key);
    return MyStateNotifier(ref.read, key);
  },
);
```

Of course, you also need to import the extension for this to work.

For the `ChangeNotifierProviderFamily` I think it would be something like this (I have not tested this):

```dart
extension ChangeNotifierProviderFamilyExtension<Notifier extends ChangeNotifier,
    Param> on ChangeNotifierProviderFamily<Notifier, Param> {
  Iterable<T> all<T extends ChangeNotifierProvider<Notifier>>(Reader read) {
    return read(_notifierFamilyKeysStorageProvider(this))
        .state
        .map((key) => call(key) as T);
  }

  Set<dynamic> keys(Reader read) =>
      read(_notifierFamilyKeysStorageProvider(this)).state;
  void addKey(Reader read, dynamic key) => this.keys(read).add(key);
}

final _notifierFamilyKeysStorageProvider =
    StateProvider.family<Set<dynamic>, ChangeNotifierProviderFamily>(
        (ref, key) {
  return {};
});
```